# How to tell Universal app to support only retina devices

Tags: ios, retina-display

the title pretty much says it all. I have a universal project which i want to support only retina devices.. is this possible? maybe i should change some settings or Info.plist, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Do you want to exclude devices, or do you want to run all devices with a single set of textures ?

Comment: exclude devices i want to run them only on device which support retina

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not support a way to support only retina devices because they see it as "either you support the family, or you find another family" kind of thing.

With that said, you can detect screen size and go from there. In my case, I use xx.png and xx@2x.png for retina (as Apple suggest) when developing for iOS and OS X devices.

Here is a link to iOS Screen sizes I used as a cheat sheet: http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/the-ios-7-design-cheat-sheet/

Comment: ok i find this "#IS_RETINA ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0)" can i use this? to check whether load or not... and how to tell app to not load? crash, and will apple approve this?

Comment: It's always a shot, but if you use this you will still need to find the difference between iPhone/iPad's as they are two different sizes. Again refer to what I said above for that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `UIDevice` class as so:

```
NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
```

Where you can check the device and if it's not retina e.g. ipad2, you stop your app from the AppDelegate.
Also there is this project for make it the model checking easier https://github.com/InderKumarRathore/UIDevice-Hardware
BTW if you are submitting this to the appstore I don't think they would approve.

Comment: is this true about not approving?

Comment: In App store review guidelines on point 2.10 which is `iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution`I understand this as "you should support all actual devices"